# Rendering React Components from an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

Suppose I have the following object that takes components as entries:

```
import Comp1 from './Comp1'
import Comp2 from './Comp2'
import Comp3 from './Comp3'

const components = { 'comp1' : Comp1, 'comp2' : Comp2, 'comp3' : Comp3 }
```

I would like to use this object to render these components:

```
Object.keys(components).map((key, i) => (

    <div key={i}> 
        <components[key] /> // this does not work
    </div>
))}
```

In reality I am trying to render routes using a config object:

```
export const routes =   {

'home' : {  
    path: '/', 
    component: Home,
    exact: true,
    access: {
        anonymous: true
    },
    navigation: {
        label: 'Home',
        icon: 'fa-home',
        show: true
    }
},
```

....

```
const Routes = () => (

    <div>

        {Object.keys(routes).map((k, i) => (

            <Route 
                key={i} 
                exact={routes[k].exact} 
                path={routes[k].path} 
                render={() => 

                    !routes[k].access.anonymous ? ( 

                        <Redirect to="/login"/>  

                    ) : ( 

                        <routes[k] /> // nope
                    )
                } 
            />

        ))}

    </div>
)
```

I was thinking that `<components[key] />` is JSX and  React does not require the use of JSX, so perhaps the solution is to render these components *without* JSX, using standard JS. Though I not sure how to do that.

Comment: Try `var Component = components[key]` (note the capital 'C'). Then use `<Component />`.

Comment: I tried this but where in the component can make that variable definition?  `Object.keys(components).map((key, i) => (
    var Component = components[key]; // Unexpected token error
    <div key={i}> 
        <Component /> // this does not work
    </div>
))}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`routes[k]` is not a React component, `routes[k].component` is. Also, since you are only interested in the values use `Object.values` instead of `Object.keys`.

```
Object.values(routes).map((route, i) => (
    <Route key={i} 
           exact={route.exact} 
           path={route.path} 
           render={() => 
              !route.access.anonymous ? ( 
                  <Redirect to="/login"/>  
              ) : ( 
                  <route.component /> 
              )
          } 
      />
  ))
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/7wn3v8x3n1)

Comment: yes, you are correct! unfortunately, I formulated the question incorrectly in an attempt to simplify the issue. Im actually trying to do this using an object, rather than an array. In reality this is a larger object where the component to be rendered is a few levels down. I have updated my question accordingly